# Is it possible to add a redirect to webkitNotfications?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

The webkitNotifications API in Chrome won't let me redirect to a page when the user clicks on the notification.

Is there any way I can make it work like Growl on the Mac, with a notification popping up, and then the user clicking on it to be redirected? For example, the user receives a new message, is notified via webkitNotifications, clicks on the message and is taken to message.php.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this (onclick)

```
    function setNotifJL(strtitre,strmsg) {
    if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0 ) {
    Window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('../mypic.gif',strtitre, strmsg);
    n.show();
    n.onclose = notify;
    n.onclick = nclicked;
    }
    }
    function notify() {location.href='<whereever you want';}
```